# Rails validation error messages displays the error messages and array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I am working through the Ruby-on-Rails3 Tutorial Chapter 8.

I have created a form that a user submits to sign up to a site.

The validations are set in the model. They have been tested and are working.

The problem is that when I display the validation error messages doing the following:

```
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
            <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")%>
            prohibited this user from being saved:  
        </h2>
        <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
        <ul>
        <%= @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>   
    </div>

<% end %>
```

I not only get the validation messages but the actual array is shown as well:

```
2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:

There were problems with the following fields:

    Password can't be blank
    Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
    **["Password can't be blank", "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]**
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why.
Anyone know how to stop this from displaying?

Thanks in advance.

This is Rails3.0.7 Ruby 1.9.2 OSX10.6

Comment: My bad I used <%=@user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%> instead of <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|

Comment: Post your comment in an answer and then accept it so the question shows as answered

Answer (score -17, accepted):

My bad I used

```
<%=@user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%>
```

instead of

```
<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
```

Comment: Which is what @Mikhail said.  You might want to delete this and select his answer as correct.

Comment: Don't mind me... Just copying the right answer so I can accept it myself.

Comment: actually he figured it out in the comments before Mikhail

Answer (score 39):

```
  <%= @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
       <li><%= message %></li>
```

You printing array with this line   `<%= @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>` delete `=` from it.