# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass for displaying Rails validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am getting an `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass error` when attempting to display errors in a view from validations in Rails. I followed this example [Rails validation error messages displays the error messages and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289470/rails-validation-error-messages-displays-the-error-messages-and-array), taking its answer into account.

An example of a validation I have in the user model is:
         `validates_length_of :dog_name, minimum: 0, maximum: 30, message: 'cannot have more than 30 characters'`

**View code**

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    #before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy,
    #:following, :followers]
    before_filter :requireLogin
    #before_action :requireDog

    def requireLogin
        if session[:user_id] == nil
            redirect_to "/"
        end
    end

    def requireDog
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        if(@user.dog_name == "Empty")
            redirect_to "users/new/"
        end
    end

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(profile_params)
            redirect_to action: "show"
            # Handle a successful update.
            else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def following
        @title = "Following"
        @user  = User.find(params[:id])
        @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
        render 'show_follow'
    end

    def followers
        @title = "Followers"
        @user  = User.find(params[:id])
        @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
        render 'show_follow'
    end

    def going
        @title = "Going"
        @user  = User.find(params[:id])
        @users = @user.going.paginate(page: params[:page])
        render 'show_gather'
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(profile_params)
        if @user.save
            redirect_to '/users'
            else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def profile_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:dog_name, :photo, :dog_breed, :dog_gender, :dog_age)
    end

end
```

In other examples the user model/controller did not need to be further modified. The user does indeed exist. Am I missing something in the model or controller?

Comment: Can you update your question with the controller method that holds the `@user`?

Comment: you are getting @user nil in your case, please add your controller code here

Comment: @Pavan, done, sorry.

Comment: why do you set both `@user` and `@current_user`?

Comment: `@user` is the user to which the page belongs, and `@current_user` is the user that is currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'd be better switching to the new [`validates` methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :dog_name, length: { in: 0..30, message: 'cannot have more than 30 characters'}
end
```

-

Secondly, instead of setting `@title` each time - why don't you just use [`action_name`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActionController%2FBase%3Aaction_name)?

Each time you load an action, the `controller_name` and `action_name` variables are set by default, to be used either in your controller or views. Why not just use the `action_name` variable in your view?

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<title><%= action_name if controller_name == "Users" %></title>
```

---

To answer your question, the error is caused because you're trying to invoke a method on a non-existent variable:

```
for nil:NilClass
```

Ruby has a funny way of posting exceptions for undeclared variables -- instead of outwardly saying the variable doesn't exist, it invokes it under the `NilClass` class.

As a developer, you're then expected to read the message of `undeclared method` and surmise that it's the variable which isn't set...

The fix for your problem is therefore to find **why the variable is not set**:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @user = User.new
   end

   def create
      @user = User.new profile_params
      redirect_to users_path if @user.save
   end
end
```

The above should give you the ability to save the user, else it will re-render the `new` action (and show the error).

I think the problem you have is that you're explicitly loading the `new` action on validation problems, which will prevent it appending the required data.